What is the difference between "Crew weight" and "Occupant Limit"?
On page 11 of the Eurofox POH it states:

Max crew weight per seat......................................................83 kg (Note: occupant limit is 100kgs per seat)

What does this mean? What is the difference between "Crew weight" and "Occupant Limit"?
Perhaps it just means if you weigh 83kg without clothes, first thing in the morning, then after adding clothes, shoes, and your on person equipment, etc. you may be up to 100kg total?

Your link doesn't seem to link to "page 11" but to the main website.

Yea the POH links are at the bottom of that page - they seem to be on a public GDrive @RalphJ

This is basically the difference between "Operational" and "Structural" limits. Quite often regulatory demand is that things like seats, harnesses, etc can withstand a higher load that you would typically expect to find in "normal" usage.
The structural limit of the seat pan appears to be 200Kg from a POH online the wording is very slightly different to the one you quoted, and perhaps gives a bit more context:

Max crew weight per seat 83 kg (Note: occupant limit is 100kgs per seat or 200kgs for the seat pan)

This is accompanied by a warning which seems to backup my assertion that this is a structural rather than operational limitation:

WARNING
Make sure that above mentioned weight limits are strictly followed.
Structural failures which result from overloading of the aircraft may be dramatic and catastrophic.

Further qualification is also included

The additional stress placed on the structural parts by overloading can accelerate the occurrence of metal fatigue failures. Also flight characteristics might change significantly when the aircraft is overloaded. Takeoff and landing distance are significantly longer for overloaded aircraft. Overloading and out of balance loading of the aircraft is one of the most common causes of accidents

What this tells me is that at 83Kg you're well within the limits of the seat pan. Although structurally, you are safe between 83 and 100Kg per seat, you're increasingly stressing the structure to it's limit which if continued over time may result in structural failure. You basically, wouldn't want to be regularly flying round with two 100Kg people or for extended periods of time.

Thanks Jamie, it's a shame they can't be built to be stronger than that

Two 83Kg adults as a fairly decent lifting capacity for such a small aircraft don't you think? I'd be worried about a 100Kg person being able to get in and out a light aircraft easily.

Since they list # of seats as 2, might "crew" be the pilot, front seat, and "occupant" be the other seat?
